# Resharper Insanity

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

Using the latest version of Resharper (4.5.x) with VS2008.

Every now and then (pretty often actually), I lose intellisense.  I then have to go into Tools/Options/Text Editor/C# and turn on 'Auto List Members' and 'Parameter Information'.  That turns it back on.

If I work without Resharper, this problem does not occur.  I am not sure whether this is a bug in Resharper or some option that I can't seem to find in the cornucopia that is the Options dialog in Resharper.

Any solutions?

Comment: If you don't find the answer here, you might try reposting on http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/community/resharper/resharper_community?view=discussions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try go to ReSharper/Options/IntelliSense/General and select Visual Studio mode.